# How to groupBy a value, sum one column and keep equal values in another?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

If you have a DataFrame with values that appear together, but also have an independent value, like so:

```
df = {'address': ["A", "A", "B"], 'balances': [30, 40, 50], 'sessions': ["V","V","K"]}
```

and you'd like to `groupby` both both and `aggregate` the other:

```
>>> df.groupby(["address"]).agg({'balances': 'sum', 'sessions': ??? })

{'address': ["A", "B"], 'balances': [80, 50], 'sessions': ["V","K"]}
```

Comment: take the first or last something like : `df.groupby(["address"]).agg({'balances': 'sum', 'sessions': 'first'})`

Comment: post an answer I can accept please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just take the first or the last in the aggregate:

```
df.groupby(["address"],as_index=False).agg({'balances': 'sum', 'sessions': 'first'})
```

---

```
  address  balances sessions
0       A        70        V
1       B        50        K
```